# How check for errors with powershell sql

Tags: sql, powershell, error-handling

I need to check for general errors with my sql, like make sure it connects ok, make sure it returns with the query results ok, etc.  I tried try/catch, but even though I know my login is wrong, it's not finding an error with the catch.  I had found the try/catch idea at [try catch](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172886/how-to-catch-error-from-sql-server-on-powershell).

How do I identify or catch when it doesn't logon to the db, or returns 0 results?

This is what I have so far:

```
function SQLQueryWriteToFile([string]$SQLquery, [string]$extractFile, [string]$facility)
{
   #create sql connection to connect to the sql DB

   try{
      $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection


      $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=blah;Database=blah;User ID=blah;Password=blah"  #sql connection
      $sqlConnection.Open()

      #Create a SqlCommand object to define the query
      $sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
      $sqlCmd.CommandText = $SQLquery
      $sqlCmd.Parameters.Add('@facility',$facility)
      $sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection

      #create a SqlAdapter that actually does the work and manages everything
      $sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
      $sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCmd
      $sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=300  #set timeout for query execution to 5 minutes (60x5=300)

      #create an empty dataSet for the query to fill with its results
      $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

      #execute the query and fill the dataSet (then disconnect)
      $sqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
      $sqlConnection.Close()


      #dump the data to csv
      $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile #this may not be comma delimited...need to check
   } #try
   catch{
      if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) #if there was an error, record it
      {
         Write-host $PSItem.ToString()
         $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Exception: $LASTEXITCODE ; $PSItem.ToString()  ")
      }
      else
      {
         $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Exception: $LASTEXITCODE ; $PSItem.ToString()  ")
      }
   } #catch
}
```

Comment: As an aside: your `try` block doesn't call external programs, so there's no point in checking `$LASTEXITCODE`.

Comment: Which statement, specifically, triggers the error (that you think isn't caught)? Is it `$sqlConnection.Open()`?

Comment: How about some `throw` in `If` statements, to check in between if everything has gone as planed so far?

Comment: When I ran the program with the wrong credentials, powershell didn't show an error message.  It just ended more quickly.  @mklement0

Comment: @T-Me, I'm not sure what to throw!

Comment: After the Connection should be established, test `if` the connection works. `Else` `throw` your own exception.

Comment: See `$sqlConnection.State`

Comment: @t-me - I added something for sqlConnectionState.  Good ideas.  Thanks! Any idea for if the query didn't complete correctly, like, I know one query last night failed because I had both my test DB and my production DB, in one query, with the connection string for the production DB.  So the results were empty that wrote to the file.  I guess if any results are empty that would be a failure.  Any ideas?

Comment: 1.: Change the `$ErrorActionPreference` so that an Error will abort the iteration. 2: Make the parameter of the function `mandatory` 3: Some more `throws` :)